# How can I delete/forget/destroy a set of radio buttons that were generated with a for loop from a list?

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

I am a teacher making a basic mini Steam client as a learning exercise for my programming class. We are using Python and tkinter.

The program generates two sets of radio buttons. The first is the users "game library" where they can select a game to play(when selecting a radio button nothing happens other than a label informs the user the game is about to be launched). The second set of radio buttons lets users select a new game to "purchase". Both sets of radio buttons are generated with a for loop and a list.

Problem:
What I want to do is have it so if you select a game to "purchase" it is added to the user_library list, then destroy/forget the original set of game library radio buttons, then regenerate the radiobuttons with a for loop. This should now also make a button for the newly added game.

The "forget" code I have tried only hides/removes the last raido button generated by the for loop.

Note: radio buttons are being used for demonstration purposes, I understand that a drop down menu would be better.

I planned to do this with a method that was connected to the purchase button.

1. The method would first append the user_library list with the new game title. 2.Then destroy/forget the user library radio buttons that were generated by the for loop when the program first started. 3. Use another for loop to recreate the user library radio buttons.

When I run the program the "forget" code I have tried only hides/removes the last raidobutton generated by the for loop.

The below code is abbreviated, but should show what I'm trying to do. I am comfortable with appending the lists, but don't understand why only the last radio button is being forgotten.

I am open to better ways of achieving the problem

```py
libraryGames=["The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt GOTE", "Jurassic World: Evolution", "Red Dead Redemption 2","Mass Effect Trilogy","Subnautica",]

saleGames=["SteamPunk 2077", 29.99, "Fallout 3", 3.99, "Warcraft 4: About dam time", 69.99, "Lego: Terminator", 19.99, "Homework simulator", 14.99]

def __init__(self, parent):
     #list that created the library game buttons

     for games in range (0, len (libraryGames)):
            rb = Radiobutton(frame1, variable = self.library_game, bg = 
            "#000000",fg="#ffffff", value = games, text = 
            libraryGames[games],command = self.library_choice)
            rb.grid(row = libraryrow, column=0, columnspan = 2,padx=25, 
            sticky=W,)
            libraryrow+=1

     #list that created the sale game buttons

     for items in range (0, len (saleGames),2):
            rb2 = Radiobutton(frame2, variable = self.sale_game, bg = 
            "#000000",fg="#ffffff",value = items, text = 
            saleGames[items],command = self.sale_choice)
            rb2.grid(row = salerow, column=0, columnspan = 2,padx=25, 
            sticky=W,)
            salerow+=1

#method that removes the radio buttons generated by the first loop when a purchase button is clicked.

def purchase(self):
        rb.grid_forget()
        # I would then add the loop code to create the radio buttons again
```

Comment: To destroy/forget a widget, you need the reference to it. In your case, `rb` is holding only the reference to one widget which is the last created in loop. So yes, you should use a list to store references to all the radio buttons to destory/forget them all.

Comment: Hi Kamal, thanks for your answer, I am not sure about creating the reference list though and how each button would use it. Would it be something like: referencelist[] then each time the for loop creates a button append a value like g1 for the first button then g2 for the second button into referencelist and so on? if so then do you simply g1.grid_forget()? sorry if this is a stupid question, but I'm pretty new to GUI

Comment: You append them to a list when you create each radio button in your for loop. Later simply loop through the list and call `grid_forget` on each item in your list

Comment: Hi Henry, thanks for your input. I am still a bit fuzzy, I don't understand how the list reference is actually linked to each button. Does the loop use this new list to rename rb or something? Is there any chance you can share some code to clarify?

Answer (score 2):

First create a list to hold the radio buttons, and then loop through the list to `grid_forget` them when required.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

libraryGames=["The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt GOTE", "Jurassic World: Evolution", "Red Dead Redemption 2","Mass Effect Trilogy","Subnautica",]

class GUI:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        frame1 = tk.Frame(parent)
        frame1.pack()
        self.holder_list = []

        for num,game in enumerate(libraryGames):
            rb = tk.Radiobutton(frame1, bg="#000000",fg="#ffffff",
                                value=game, text=game,command= "",selectcolor="grey")
            rb.grid(row = num, column=0, columnspan = 2,padx=25,sticky=tk.W,)
            self.holder_list.append(rb)

        frame2 = tk.Frame(parent)
        frame2.pack()
        tk.Button(frame2,text="Purchased",command=self.purchase).pack()

    def purchase(self):
        print (self.holder_list)
        for widget in self.holder_list:
            widget.grid_forget()

GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you for this, its really helpful, I appreciate you taking the time.

Comment: No problem, i like the list of your library games.